# Irrationality of the sum of the reciprocal of perfect powers

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

A couple of days ago I was trying to remember a classical exercise (which I now find out goes by the name of [Goldbach-Euler theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach-Euler_theorem)). Eventually I figured out that it asked to prove that $$\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}} \frac1{p-1} = 1,$$ where $\mathcal{P} = \{n^a \mid n,a \ge 2\}$ is the set of powers of integers.

At the beginning, though, I thought that the sum I was looking for was $$\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}} \frac1{p}$$
instead. The identity above tells us that the sum converges to some $S<1$.

> Is $S$ known to be irrational? Is it known to be ***_*__*_*___**?

Here the blank can be filled by anything like: algebraic, transcendental, transcendental over $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$, trascendental over $\mathbb{Z}[\pi, \log2, \log3, \dots]$...

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power#Examples_and_sums) says that $S\approx 0.874464368$, which makes me think that not too much is known, other than the (somewhat trivial) identity $S = \sum \mu(n)(1-\zeta(n))$...

Comment: The sum is probably over $\mathcal{P}$ *without duplications*, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectPower.html.

Comment: Yes, otherwise the inequality wouldn't be trivial (well, in fact the sum would be exactly 1).

Comment: Many more digits are given (but no arithmetical information) at https://oeis.org/A072102